# Passing select statement as parameter to scalar function in SQL

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions

I have scalar function which takes an integer as argument and return an integer too. I was trying to use this function by passing a parameter as a select statement which looks like :

`select dbo.scalarFunc(select si.ID from table1 si where version = 9)`

It would not let me do it. I tried cast but still did not work. Can anyone tell me if I can use select inside like this or not?

Comment: Note that `si` is an undefined alias in your query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good way to write this is :

```
select dbo.scalarFunc(table1.ID) from table1 where version = 9
```

And if you want to use it later :

```
select * from table2 where ID = (select dbo.scalarFunc(table1.ID) from table1 where version = 9)
```

Comment: If you want to use it later I'd suggest capturing it into a variable the first time instead.